# Flutter App failed to make HTTP request on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, dart, httprequest, flutter, request-timed-out

I tried to make a simple HTTP get request using [Dio](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio) in a Flutter App like this:

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
Response response = await dio.get('https://www.baidu.com');
print(response.data.toString());
```

It works perfect on a real iOS device, but time out on iOS simulators.

```
SocketException: OS Error: Operation timed out, errno = 60
```

I also tried other packets such as [http](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http), but still time out. Native apps running on the simulator doesn't have the same problem. 
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: @Ramprasathselvam As you can see, I'm making an HTTPS request. Not for this reason, thanks.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: flutter Http package can't use system proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the API's are working in simulator, I assume this is due to your systems proxy settings since it uses your machines internet. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with `Dio` using the below code in iOS simulator, if you want to see how `http` work check the [cookbook](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/), also try connecting to an open network like home wifi or something and see...

Note: This is a piece from iOS/ Android flutter project

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  fetchData()async {

    Dio dio = new Dio();
    Response response=await dio.get('https://www.baidu.com');
    print(response.data);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: new IconButton(icon:new Icon(Icons.all_inclusive) , onPressed: (){
            fetchData();
          })
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

RESPONSE

```
flutter: <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--STATUS OK-->

<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta content="always" name="referrer">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#2932e1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/content-search.xml" title="百度搜索" />
    <link rel="icon" sizes="any" mask href="//www.baidu.com/img/baidu_85beaf5496f291521eb75ba38eacbd87.svg">


    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s1.bdstatic.com"<…>
```